# JSON file not being read with Angular $HTTP Get in MEAN.JS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, meanjs

I am developing a Web application with MEAN.JS (www.meanjs.org) and I am trying to use an AngularJS $HTTP Get request with a JSON file in my controller, so that I can pull data from it within one of my pages. For some odd reason, the JSON file (foo.json) is never read. Even when I simply try to reach the file via http://localhost:3000/foo.json it does not show. Nor does it show in the console with any errors. I have placed the JSON file everywhere within my module, the root directory, the view directory etc, you name it. Only when I use a longer path name like "modules/core/json/foo.json" do I get a Chrome console error with a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" Error. This is my controller code:

```
angular.module('core').controller('FooController', ['$scope', '$http',
function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('foo.json').success(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  $scope.products = data;
});
}
]);
```

FOO.JSON file placed in the root of my Core module folder, in the views, and even in the root directory of the app.

```
[
  {

        "id" : 3,
        "name": "Orange Theme",
        "description": "Consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum turpis nec nunc scelerisque convallis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas id diam enim.",
        "type": "Joomla",
        "price": 12.99,
        "images": [
            {
                "name": "orange.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "name": "Gray Theme",
        "description": "Consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum turpis nec nunc scelerisque convallis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas id diam enim.",
        "type": "Joomla",
        "price": 12.99,
        "images": [
            {
                "name": "gray.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 5,
        "name": "Purple Theme",
        "description": "Consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum turpis nec nunc scelerisque convallis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas id diam enim.",
        "type": "html5",
        "price": 9.99,
        "images": [
            {
                "name": "purple.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have been frustrated with this one, as it seems so simple! Not sure if it has something to do with JSON files not being served out of the box, and I need to make changes within Express etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sharing a link on `localhost` is not going to make it (localhost is current machine). Consider pasting the `foo.json` as a code segment or a part of it. Is the code given executes on `localhost:3000` - on the same place where is `foo.json`?

Comment: @Rolice Just posted Foo.json. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. And are the code executed on the same host - `localhost:3000`. This looks to me as network error, most likely. Use the `$http`.`error` promise to debug the issue, like: `$http.get(..).success(..).error(function(error) { console.log(error); });`. Then you will see the issue in the browser console.

Comment: UPDATE: To help debug when I change the controller code to:

      angular.module('core').controller('ShawlsController', ['$scope', '$http',
      function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('products.json').success(function(data){
          $scope.products = data;
        }).error(function(data) {
        // error handler
        });
      }
    ]);

Comment: I receive the following console error in Chrome:

angular.js:11706 
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: product in products, Duplicate key: string:<, Duplicate value: <
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=product%20in%20products&p1=string%3A%3C&p2=%3C
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at ngRepeatAction (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:24772:21)

Comment: at Object.$watchCollectionAction (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:14279:13)
    at Object.arguments.(anonymous function) [as fn] (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1345:36)
    at Scope.$digest

Comment: (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:14412:29)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1364:23)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:14675:24)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1427:22)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:9725:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:9915:7)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11706

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your JSON file is not reachable from a browser, it sounds like you're not serving static files from Node. In your node app.js file, you need to initialise the relevant middleware to serve static files - for example, to serve the files in directory 'public' inside your node application, add:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If the file is in the root of your Node application, it won't be reachable over HTTP by default. Therefore, if you put your JSON file in directory named public and include the above line in your node app.js file, it should then be reachable at http://localhost:3000/foo.json

Comment: Thanks Mark. This was the solution. Very much appreciated! I have built a classic Node and Express application before (non-MEAN.JS) and that's how I served all my static assets. In the case with this MEAN.JS application, since I was successful in rendering image files within the modules directory themselves, it made me think that it was open game for JSON files to be put there as well. Since I was unable to view the JSON file in the browser I knew something was up with regards to this. This really helped. I appreciate all the help from everyone on here!

Comment: NOTE: For anyone reading this who had the issue I had, if you are using MEAN.JS you don't need to enhance your app.js file to initialize middleware (as Mark has pointed out), as this has already been done for you. You only need to store such static files etc in your "Public" folder in order for them to be served. You only need to do add Mark's line of code in your main app.js/server.js file if you are building an Express.JS app from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to add the JSON data to a mongodb database and retrieve the data from there. I have used $hhtp to request some data from the controller like this.

Create a service to retrieve the data through $http:

```
angular
.module('yourModule')
.factory('YourService', function($http) {
  var urlBase = '/api/restfull/url';
  var aService = {};

  aService.getThemes = function() {
    return $http.get(urlBase);
  };
  return aService;
});
```

in your controller inject `YourService` and do this:

```
YourService.getThemes().then(function(data) {
  vm.themes = data.data;
});
```

On your server side add the specific route `'/api/restfull/url'` like this

```
 app.route('/api/restfull/url').all(sitesPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(themes.getThemes);
```

in your server controller handle the request and respond with the mongodb JSON data:

```
exports.getThemes = function(req, res) {
  Themes.find().exec(function(err, themes) { //Themes is your mongodb instance
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(themes);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've reduced your example to

```
<body ng-app="core">
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <div ng-repeat="product in products">
            {{ product }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('core', []);

        app.controller('FooController', function($scope, $http){
            $http.get('foo.json')
                    .success(function(data){
                        console.log(data);      // data appears on console
                        $scope.products = data;
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        console.log(err);       // error if any
                    });
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

and using your JSON file I get the correct output.

From your comments above (sorry I cannot comment yet), it looks like you have an issue in the ng-repeat part of your code. If you are using another JSON file you may be getting key errors in ng-repeat in which case the follow may help

`<div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index"></div>`

per the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was very much appreciated!

Comment: Was that it? Just so that we can tell if someone else has this issue?

Comment: Sorry. I see you had a path error. Thanks for the nod

Comment: Yep. That was it. See my comments under the chosen answer/green check mark. Again, I really appreciated your help nonetheless!